# index.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null ( at toggleActiveOnClick and at Array.forEach)

Tags: javascript

For a project I have to evolve a piece of code but I can not. This bit of code initially allows me to toggle the 4 clickable elements of a certain form and it works perfectly.

```
const choices = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable');

const toggleActiveClass = (event) => {
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
};

const toggleActiveOnClick = (choice) => {
  choice.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveClass);
};

choices.forEach(toggleActiveOnClick);
```

However, now I have to make sure that when I select one or the other of the first 2 elements I can not toggle the other and the same for the next 2. I tried this piece of code but when I open the console in chrome tool i get the error message present in the title of this post. Here is the piece of code in question:

```
const upsell = document.querySelector('.clickable > .fas fa-shopping-cart');
const crossell = document.querySelector('.clickable > .fas fa-cart-plus');
const standard = document.querySelector('.clickable > .fas fa-gift');
const discount = document.querySelector('.clickable > .fas fa-percent');

const choices = [ upsell, crossell, standard, discount ];

const toggleActiveClass = (event) => {
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
};

const toggleActiveOnClick = (choice) => {
  if (choice === upsell.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveClass)) {
    crossell.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (choice === crossell.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveClass)) {
    upsell.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (choice === standard.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveClass)) {
    discount.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (choice === discount.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveClass)) {
    standard.classList.remove('active');
  }
};

choices.forEach(toggleActiveOnClick);
```

Here is the corresponding html

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="bundle-type">Bundle Type</label>
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center pt-4">
            <div id="test1">
              <div class="clickable">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                <small>Upsell</small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test2">
              <div class="clickable">
                <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                <small>Cros-sell</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <label for="bundle-type">Offer Type</label>
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center pt-4">
            <div id="test3">
              <div class="clickable">
                <i class="fas fa-gift"></i>
                <small>Standard</small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test4">
              <div class="clickable">
                <i class="fas fa-percent"></i>
                <small>Discounted</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.clickable i {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clickable:hover i {
  color: #167FFB;
}

.clickable.active {
  color: inherit;
  border-color: inherit;
}

.clickable.active i {
  color: #0F60C4;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this `if (choice === upsell.addEventListener(...)) { }` to do?

Comment: Please show us your HTML as well!

Comment: if (choice === upsell.addEventListener(...)) { }                                                             Normally this should allow me to make sure that when I select the 1st element I can no longer toggle the 2nd element associated

Comment: _Normally_ this won't ever work. Check the documentation for `.addEventListener()` on what it does and what it returns. Hint:you don't want it in your `if...else...` block

Comment: I don't understand it's possible to be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are just wrong, and you could have verified them (`upsell` and the others) with debugging/logging.
`class="fas fa-shopping-cart"` asssigns two classes to the element, `fas` and `fa-shopping-cart`. While it may be possible that after digesting the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) someone can come up with a selector for multiple classes, you could simply ignore `fas` (which is the same for all of them), and go for the specific ones instead:

```js
console.log("Original attempt:");
const upsell = document.querySelector('.clickable > .fas fa-shopping-cart');
const crossell = document.querySelector('.clickable > .fas fa-cart-plus');
console.log(upsell);
console.log(crossell);

console.log("Simplified attempt:");
const upsellSimple = document.querySelector('.clickable > .fa-shopping-cart');
const crossellSimple = document.querySelector('.clickable > .fa-cart-plus');
console.log(upsellSimple);
console.log(crossellSimple);
```

```html
<label for="bundle-type">Bundle Type</label>
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center pt-4">
  <div id="test1">
    <div class="clickable">
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
      <small>Upsell</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="test2">
    <div class="clickable">
      <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
      <small>Cros-sell</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

What others tried to point out: [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) has no meaningful return value:

> Return value: `undefined`

The comparisons (`if (choice === xy.addEventListener(...)){...}`) can not really do anything useful.